# CodenameOne Ios Build fails with "No certificate matching '<apple id >(#####385)' found"

Tags: codenameone

The ios build, for a codename one app, started failing on server, although previously this was building without problems. I have changed nothing in the app config. The apple certificate and the provisioning profile are active.

The Xcode build option is set to Default.

The error I get from the building server is this:

> Code Signing Error: No certificate matching 'apple id
>   (######385)' found:  Select a different signing certificate for
>   CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY, a team that matches your selected certificate, or
>   switch to automatic provisioning.

I have tried regenerating the provisioning profile, but I get the same error.

The same error appears both for debug and release builds.

Help!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have manged to get a succesful server build, both for debug and release versions, by setting the xcode version to 7.3. The default version used was 9.2, which causes the builds to fail.

Although this works, I don't know if there are any implications of using the older xcode version for building.

Comment: Apple will stop accepting new app submissions with 7.3 in April if I remember correctly and shortly after that will stop accepting updates too. If you just need to push out an update you can do this and it should be OK. When you have time I suggest revoking and regenerating the certificates as it might be something we already fixed in the certificate generation process/provisioning. If it doesn't fix it we'll need more details for this issue.

Comment: @ShaiAlmog I seem to be having the same problem - app store build fails with the above error with xcode 9.2, but succeeds with xcode 7.3. I tried regenerating certificates, but the problem persists. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Did you regenerate using the wizard or manually? The wizard should work correctly but you need to review what it did and make sure the paths to the certificates etc are correct. If it's still a problem review the cn1libs you use and other things, make sure everything is up to date in the extension manager. If it still fails contact support chat with the link to the fail log